# How to get User Id and Access Token in Microsoft Graph API C#

Tags: c#, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to create a multi-tenant app that will allow users to access their OneDrive.  Due to the type of device that the app will be run on, it is not practical to have users entering their username and password each time they access the app, so I was going to setup the app so that an administrator can grant permissions on behalf of their users using the app only permissions (I have the admin consenting bit done).

The bit I am having trouble with now is that when a user accesses the app, I only have their email address.

How can I get an access token based on the user's email address without them having to sign-in (their admin has already consented, so the user shouldn't have too)?

Answer (score 0):

If the admin has already consented, you can use the possibility to [login without the user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) and retrieve a token.

How do I get the OneDrive?

1. You stated that you have the user's email, so you could perform the query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email address}` and take the value of the `id` field.
2. Perform the query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/drive` and you have the drive of the user.

Comment: I did think that calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email address}` would be the way to get the user id.  The bit I am not understanding is that you you need the tenant id to get an access token before you can call that, or do I have that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Andy

According to [this reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) we can get an AccessToken by some background services or daemons.

Based on my test, we can try the following steps:
1. Get administrator consent:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
         ClientId = clientId,
         Authority = authority,
         RedirectUri = redirectUri,
         PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
         Scope = "openid profile",
         ResponseType = "id_token",
         TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, NameClaimType = "name" },
         Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                             {
                                    AuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                                    SecurityTokenValidated = this.OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                              }
   });

ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId), Startup.redirectUri,
                                                                                       new ClientCredential(Startup.clientSecret), null, appTokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance());
```

AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { MSGraphScope });

2. We can get the user by the email from the url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}`. For example,`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx.outlook.com`

For more details, we can refer to  [v2.0 daemon sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2) on GitHub.

Comment: This will work if you have the tenant id already, but unfortunately, I don't have that, is there a way to either find out the tenant id, or is it possible to get an access token from the `/common` endpoint?

Comment: Do you have problem for finding the tenant id? If so, you can find out the tenant id form the Url: [link](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList). If I misunderstood what you mean, please let me know.

Comment: The users will be sign-in onto the device by swiping a card which only exposes their email address, so from that, I need to be able to get the tenant id and then I would be able to query the users to get the user id.

Comment: In the simple code, the tenant id could be find `UserController/Index`. Or you can request the Url `https://login.windows.net/{your company}.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` to get the tenant id. The parameter of  ` your company ` can be get by the user's email. Example, the user's email like this `xxx@kegen.onmicrosoft.com` , the company parameter will be `kegen` . A bunch of data will be returned, and right there in the first line is your tenant ID.  Bookmark this link, and you will be to get it in seconds,  for whenever you need it